# Multiple Joins with Hibernate but with different columns

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I need to recreate this query:

```sql
select distinct
  limits.domains_limit,
  limits.emails_limit,
  limits.keywords_limit
from user_schema.tenant_limits as limits
join user_schema.tenant as tenants on limits.tenant_id = tenants.id
join profile_schema.profile as profiles on tenants."name" = 'test'
```

The relevant part of the tables I have to go through are:

```
    PROFILE(Table)
    - Tenant (refer to TENANTS.name)

    TENANTS (Table)
     - id
     - name

    LIMITS (Table)
     - tenant_id (refer to TENANTS.id)
```

And what I basically need to do is given a Profile (which contains a tenant name) I need to fetch the limits for the tenant. How can I set it up with Hibernate Annotations?

Profile.java

```java
public class Profile {

  // other properties ...

  @Column(name = "tenant", nullable = false, updatable = false)
  private String tenant;

  //How to fetch limits here?
  private ProfileLimits limits;
}
```

TenantsLimit

```java
public class ProfileLimits {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long tenant_id;

    @Column(name = "domains_limit", nullable = true, updatable = true)
    private Long domains;
    @Column(name = "emails_limit", nullable = true, updatable = true)
    private Long emails;
    @Column(name = "keywords_limit", nullable = true, updatable = true)
    private Long keywords;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understood your question. Can you clarify? Do you need information regarding the annotations @ManyToMany? Do you have a sql join doubt? I was a bit confused while reading your question. Best regards

Comment: Sorry for confusion. 

It is a OneToOneToOne relation. PROFILE.tenant(name) -> TENANT <- LIMITS.tenant_id

I can't manage to recreate this kind of relationshiip between Profile and Limits. They both relate to Tenants but with different columns